# what does mean of the return values of platform.python_version_tuple()

Tags: python, platform

Can anybody please explain about the return values of platform.python_version_tuple()? What is major, minor and patch level? what is the significance of using these?

Answer (score 1):

As always, reading the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/platform.html#platform.python_version_tuple) helps.

You can even do this directly in IDLE:

```
>>> import platform
>>> help(platform.python_version_tuple)
Help on function python_version_tuple in module platform:

python_version_tuple()
    Returns the Python version as tuple (major, minor, patchlevel)
    of strings.

    Note that unlike the Python sys.version, the returned value
    will always include the patchlevel (it defaults to 0).

>>> platform.python_version_tuple()
('3', '6', '1')
```

For general information about software versioning, [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_versioning) is (almost always) a good starting point.